# Firebase define Data structur

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase and want to exchange data over Rest API. I want to start to define my tables for my data structure, but no-one is explained how this works. For test I access with Postman and put data to Firebase this works fine, but how can I define a member data structure?

```
Members
 |- Id 1
    |- Name  
    |- First name
 |- Id 2
    |- Name 
    |- First name
 |- Id 3
    |- Name 
    |- First name
```

Is there anyone who had a link? Most of the time I work with SQL and I need my table data online.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a schema-less database, which might be very different from SQL background you have.

You create and structure your db as you go forward but please make sure you have in-depth understanding of how you want your database to be.

To start with (only for testing purpose) first change the security rules to public.

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Once your rules are set, you can perform read/write operations using any REST client like postman even without authentication.

To better understand firebase realtime db, think of it as a big JSON tree, and structure your data accordingly.

To perform first write operation, identify your Realtime DB URL you can find it from the firebase console and it will be like:

```
https://your-project.firebaseio.com/
```

Now open your post man and select POST and in URL field enter the above URL and append ".json" at last.

```
https://your-project.firebaseio.com/.json
```

Now select **content-type** as **application/json**

and in body enter your data you want to send in JSON format like:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

To perform read operation select GET in your REST client and enter the url

```
https://your-project.firebaseio.com/.json
```

leaving the body blank. This will help you fetch the data from firebase realtime db.

I would also recommend to go through [Firebase official doc on REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) for more details.

Comment: Yes this works i changed my rules to true and send data to firebase and it work. this is'nt the problem. but if iwant send structured data (json) to firbase i must declare the the fields that i need then i can send data, only samples with messenger app who create automatic. but i wantsend Data to firebase of member and how can i make a structur of it. that i can later read and delete.

Comment: No you don't need the field to be declared before sending data. You can simply point it via a URL.

For example:

If you want to send user name in "User" node you can try:

URL "https://your-project.firebaseio.com/User.json"

BODY: { "name": "Frank"} using POST even though there was no existing "User" node before.

If you want to get the random object id before posting the data you can use: 

String mGroupId = mGroupRef.push().getKey();

Comment: ah ok Thanks and mGroupId = mGroupRef.push().getKey(); workson postman if yes where

Comment: mGroupId = mGroupRef.push().getKey(); is to fetch the possible object id that Firebase use to push key.

You can use it on client application using Java or any preferred language you want.

But i believe that was not your question, you question was do we need any location defined before sending data. Using object key was just for the reference.

Apologies if I am unable to understand your question, I am having difficulty in understanding your English.

Comment: Great, happy to help. If the problem is resolved using this answer, kindly accept the answer.